# Getting internal links to work in a wicked_pdf generated PDF

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, pdf, wicked-pdf

I'm using [Wicked PDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) to generate a PDF from an HTML string which has internal links. When I look at the regular HTML, clicking on the link takes me to the correct place. But when I look at the generated PDF, clicking on the link doesn't work at all. Here's my code:

```
output = generate_story_html(watermark)
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(output, :disable_internal_links => false)
```

Comment: No, I ended up using wkhtmltopdf instead.